# Button with icon and number that counts something in iOS

Tags: ios, swift

I'm trying to make a button that contains an icon and a number in the top right that counts something. Something like this: [image]

How can I do it in the simplest way possible? I have been looking for articles about it but I have not found anything or I have not been able to find it.

Thanks.

Comment: Subclass `UIView` to draw a number.  Then add a tap gesture to it to make it a button.

Comment: You can just create a view with a gesture and above him circular button and for each click on this gesture increase the counter by one

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a usefull class named `SSBadgeButton` Its perfectly works.Implementation link :

https://github.com/iosRevisited/SSBadgeButton/blob/master/SSBadgeButton/SSBadgeButton.swift Implementation :

```
class SSBadgeButton: UIButton {

var badgeLabel = UILabel()

var badge: String? {
    didSet {
        addBadgeToButon(badge: badge)
    }
}

public var badgeBackgroundColor = UIColor.red {
    didSet {
        badgeLabel.backgroundColor = badgeBackgroundColor
    }
}

public var badgeTextColor = UIColor.white {
    didSet {
        badgeLabel.textColor = badgeTextColor
    }
}

public var badgeFont = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 12.0) {
    didSet {
        badgeLabel.font = badgeFont
    }
}

public var badgeEdgeInsets: UIEdgeInsets? {
    didSet {
        addBadgeToButon(badge: badge)
    }
}

override init(frame: CGRect) {
    super.init(frame: frame)
    addBadgeToButon(badge: nil)
}

func addBadgeToButon(badge: String?) {
    badgeLabel.text = badge
    badgeLabel.textColor = badgeTextColor
    badgeLabel.backgroundColor = badgeBackgroundColor
    badgeLabel.font = badgeFont
    badgeLabel.sizeToFit()
    badgeLabel.textAlignment = .center
    let badgeSize = badgeLabel.frame.size
    
    let height = max(18, Double(badgeSize.height) + 5.0)
    let width = max(height, Double(badgeSize.width) + 10.0)
    
    var vertical: Double?, horizontal: Double?
    if let badgeInset = self.badgeEdgeInsets {
        vertical = Double(badgeInset.top) - Double(badgeInset.bottom)
        horizontal = Double(badgeInset.left) - Double(badgeInset.right)
        
        let x = (Double(bounds.size.width) - 10 + horizontal!)
        let y = -(Double(badgeSize.height) / 2) - 10 + vertical!
        badgeLabel.frame = CGRect(x: x, y: y, width: width, height: height)
    } else {
        let x = self.frame.width - CGFloat((width / 2.0))
        let y = CGFloat(-(height / 2.0))
        badgeLabel.frame = CGRect(x: x, y: y, width: CGFloat(width), height: CGFloat(height))
    }
    badgeLabel.frame = CGRect(x: self.frame.maxX - self.frame.maxX/3, y: 0, width: self.frame.maxX/3, height: self.frame.maxX/3)
    
    badgeLabel.layer.cornerRadius = badgeLabel.frame.height/2
    badgeLabel.layer.masksToBounds = true
    badgeLabel.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth = true
    
    addSubview(badgeLabel)
    badgeLabel.isHidden = badge != nil ? false : true
}

required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    super.init(coder: aDecoder)
    self.addBadgeToButon(badge: nil)
    fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
}
```

}

Usage :

```
    let notificationButton = SSBadgeButton()

  notificationButton.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: "width", height: "height")
   notificationButton.setBackgroundImage(UIImage(named: "profileMessage"), for: .normal)

   notificationButton.badge = "2"
```

Comment: That looks like a copy from https://github.com/iosRevisited/SSBadgeButton/blob/master/SSBadgeButton/SSBadgeButton.swift, without attribution. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/referencing about how to properly reference material written by others.

Comment: Yes I couldnt find the link so posted the code @MartinR

Comment: I found it instantly with a Google search for "Swift SSBadgeButton" :)

Comment: I use yandex XD @MartinR

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way is open the Figma app, design the button you want, open source code (Figma auto-generate ).
after that, copy it to your project.

Comment: Hi Jacky, This does not provide a helpful answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment) on any post; instead, provide answers that [don't require clarification](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead) from the asker. Thanks!